# Centering a background image inside a div

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to center an image inside a div, it gets close, but still is not really centered. The image is 976x976 px. The following is the CSS:

```
div {

     margin-left: auto ;
     margin-right: auto ;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     max-width:976px;
     height:976px;
     min-width: 433px;
     padding:0;
     background: url("images/background.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

The image must to be centered, but its exorbitant at the top and right, that is: [image]

Comment: background: url("images/background.png") no-repeat center center; ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page if it's live? We'll need to see the image and code in action.

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to your div. If that does not do it, you are gonna have to show you html here (i am assuming you are centering an "image" as you said, and not the "background image" as it seems in your css, btw.

Comment: Tom, I've trying (center center).
Nerdwood, the link: http://www.cruzbranca.com/test/index.html
RAEC, I've add text-align, still the same.

Comment: The problem is that you have an image that is large than the size of your div and therefore it will not be positioned exactly in the center of your div. Not best method but you could try to use this:     `background: url("images/background.png") no-repeat 50% 18.5%;` @LeandrosLópez

Comment: Yeas @Rotan075, I'm ashamed... I've made a mistake, sorry for you guys. I was editing background.jpg thinking it was background.png... this is why don't was fitting.

Comment: Your image is in the center on your link, but the image isn't square!!!

Crop your image then your code will work. You have an extra 100px below the circular part of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your provided URL I saw that positioning the background-image is indeed positioned more towards the top due to the fact the bgimage is larger than the div itself. Therefore you need to play with the percentages.

```
background: url("images/background.png") no-repeat 50% 18.5%;
```

Could solve your problem and place the image in the center of you div

Comment: How is this different from what the OP posted, and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: This is different as I said in my post! Changing the background property to background-image does the trick. In that case the div with the background image will always be positioned in the center of the screen. @torazaburo

Comment: Really? I would have thought that specifying the url as part of the shorthand property is precisely equivalent to specifying it as the value of `background-image`. I don't know what you mean by "as I said in my post". You didn't say anything in your post. You just posted some code.

Comment: In some cases, yes! In other cases not! But looking at the provided website that Leandros López give, there is different problem. He want to have the background-image in the center of the div but the bg picture does not have the same size as the div @torazaburo

Comment: If that is the problem, then post a solution saying that that's the problem, not one which suggests a meaningless rewriting of shorthand properties to individual properties.

Comment: I modified my answer! @torazaburo

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine??
Ive changed the order of your shorthand css and used 50% instead of center.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  
     margin-left: auto ;
     margin-right: auto ;
     border:11px solid red;
     max-width:976px;
     height:976px;
     min-width: 433px;
     padding:0;
     background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-976-976-4.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Your image on your link is a rectangular image with the circle at the top so isn't square.**

**Crop that image for your code to work!**

---

Comment: I do not think you want to facilitate that every `<div>` is positioned absolute.

Comment: LOL @Rotan075, I'm just forcing the div to be 100% height and width whilst maintaining the OP's code.

Comment: Why do you need to change the order of the shorthand CSS?

Comment: because the order is incorrect. image - repeat - position is the correct order

Comment: That page merely lists the properties; it does not say they must be in that order. Consult a reliable source like MDN, where it clearly states "**in any order**" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).